# Netplan: 2 *primary* IPs in a subnet/VLAN on a single server

Tags: netplan

My application needs 2 *primary* IPs in a subnet/VLAN on a single server, which is obviously impossible when putting them on a single interface as one of them always becomes secondary. May I have a sample Netplan config with 2 subinterfaces bound to the same VLAN, so that each of them can have its own (primary) IP? I thought it was possible with pre-Netplan Ubuntu networking using VLAN10-bound subinterfaces eth1.10 and eth1.10:0:

```
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:29:DB:27:4F
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fedb:274f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

eth1.10   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:29:DB:27:4F
          inet addr:50.0.10.254  Bcast:50.0.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fedb:274f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

eth1.10:0 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:29:DB:27:4F
          inet addr:50.0.10.253  Bcast:50.0.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

When I try adding a similar subinterface with ":0" into my Netplan config:

```yaml
    vlans:
        vlan10-cp:
            addresses:
            - 50.0.10.254/24
            dhcp4: false
            dhcp6: false
            id: 10
            link: mlom
        vlan10-cp:0:
            addresses:
            - 50.0.10.253/24
            dhcp4: false
            dhcp6: false
            id: 10
            link: mlom
```

it causes a mess (the interface is not created and its IP is given to an irrelevant interface vnet0), so Netplan doesn't seem to understand the ":0" suffix and I'm struggling to find the right syntax assuming it's possible with Netplan at all.

**Update:** looks like virtual interface like my ":0" is a feature supported with Netplan v0.100 available in Ubuntu 20.04 and up (mine's v0.99 with Ubuntu 18 and I'm not allowed to upgrade it to give it a try):
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nplan/+bug/1743200

Still any other ideas on achieving the goal of having 2 *primary* IPs in a subnet/VLAN on a single server are welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @PhilipCouling: Sure: just updated my question with the Netplan config that caused a mess upon adding the subinterface with ":0" there.

Comment: 'virtual interface like my ":0"'  is actually not an interface at all but an address with a label for compatibility with the old ifconfig API. That's something to always keep in mind, because routing or firewall will only see an address.

Comment: @A.B: just got hold of an Ubuntu 16 VM (no Netplan) and tested it the old way. Looks like I was wrong: the IP on the ":0" shows up in "ip a show" output still as secondary, e.g. "inet 50.0.10.2/24 brd 50.0.10.255 scope global secondary ens5.10:0". I must've decided it's primary after seeing it in the ifconfig ":0" output and knowing that secondary IPs aren't shown in ifconfig output. I should've been using "ip a show" instead.

Comment: It's secondary because it's the same IP LAN. If you made it (whatever the mean) using an other LAN eg: 192.0.2.2/24 on the same interface, then that would be a 2nd primary address. But you never explained what's your goal with having primary addresses.

Comment: @A.B: Yeah, now it's clear that I've never actually had 2 primary IPs in the same subnet/VLAN. The goal is just to satisfy my application: some of its k8s pods won't start when the IP they use is secondary, and when I make that IP primary they seem to start fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used subinterfaces before.  Reading up on this, I don't see `:` and `.` clearly defined, or rather some references seem to use `:` for subinterfaces where others use `.`

Netplan seems to require specify creating subinterfaces under `vlans:` instead of `ethernets:`.

There are examples [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1419649/39039) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1009776/39039) on Ask Ububuntu recommending something like:

```yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens192:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses:
        - 192.168.1.1/24
  vlans:
    ens192.1:
      id: 1
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses:
        - 172.16.1.1/24
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I suspect with such config 192.168.1.1 will not make it into the VLAN defined on ens192.1, will it? ('cos it's applied to the main interface ens192) I haven't tried it though.

Comment: @dandreye noted. I'll read a bit more.  From your question I don't **think** the interface name is necessarily significant.  `:` is significant in yaml so I would try with a `.` instead.  I believe having two vlans with the same `id` is basically the right approach.  If I get any further I'll edit the answer.

Comment: thank you! Sorry it's removing "@PhilipCouling" every time I try starting my text with it.

Comment: Some interim finding here meanwhile: looks like VIFs like vlan10-cp:0 are supported through labels in 20.04 and up (bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nplan/+bug/1743200 referred from ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2405028). Their support is also mentioned wrt Ubuntu 22 Netplan at the bottom of askubuntu.com/questions/990825/virtual-interface-in-netplan.